# Is it possible to maintain an automated global list of allocated class instances in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I suspect the answer is 'no', but just in case:

I would very much like to be able to maintain a global list of 'live' instances of a class so that they may all be pumped at a particular stage in processing.

I know this is trivial to do manually (auto-add to static list when allocated, remove manually in the containing class's **finalise**, but as these instances will be sprinkled everywhere, I would prefer not to run the risk of someone forgetting to clean one of them up.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to used weak references in order to make the objects collectable at all, and then it is pointless to remove them from the list in the finalizer (which runs indeterministacally anyhow).

Comment: Without knowing more about your concrete use case it is difficult to suggest a better approach

Comment: I use a dictionary in my UnitOfWork implementation to retrieve the instances of a generic repository.
`_repositoryMap ??= new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>(); `
`var type = typeof(TEntity);`
`if (!_repositoryMap.ContainsKey(type)) 
_repositoryMap[type] = new Repository<TEntity>(_dbContext.Set<TEntity>());`
`return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositoryMap[type];` Not so sure if this is what you are after, but in the dispose method you can clear the dictionary to get rid of them.

Comment: The very interesting additional question here is "why you need this?"